# Getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function!" when running Karma test suite

Tags: node.js, karma-runner

When I try to run my the karma test suite (using `npm test` or `karma start`) of a project I get this output:

```
> game-engine@0.1.0 test /home/kent/dev/html5/game-engine
> karma start karma.conf.js --browsers PhantomJS

16 11 2015 16:50:11.910:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/
16 11 2015 16:50:11.921:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
16 11 2015 16:50:12.109:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket opYF2pU3Qw-7rkdeAAAA with id 45780972
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a function!
  at /home/kent/dev/html5/game-engine/node_modules/karma-babel-preprocessor/node_modules/babel-core/browser-polyfill.js:16

Finished in 0.12 secs / 0 secs

SUMMARY:
✔ 0 tests completed
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

If I look at line 16 of the above mentioned file it looks like it has something to do with modules:

```
module.exports = function(it){ //// Line 16
  if(typeof it != 'function')throw TypeError(it + ' is not a function!');
  return it;
};
```

The file as a whole can be found here: http://pastebin.com/quHaY4NN

I use these versions:

```
$ node --version
v4.2.2
$ npm --version
2.14.7
$ karma --version
Karma version: 0.13.15
```

I've been banging my head against this for several hours. What kind of problem could it be? How should I go about debugging it?

Comment: did you add/load your test framework library in PhantomJS ?

Comment: Same here.  Previously working with `babel-core@5.8.25` and `karma-babel-preprocessor@5.2.2`  (and using `node_modules/babel-core/browser-polyfill.min.js`).  Upgraded to `babel-core@6.2.1`, `babel-polyfill@6.2.0`, `babel-preset-es2015@6.1.181` and `karma-babel-preprocessor@6.0.1`; changed the polyfill path to `node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js` and added `presets: ['es2015']` to the preprocessor options; and I get the same `undefined is not a function` error.  Tracing back through the call stack, the `undefined` appears to be `window.setImmediate`.

Comment: Do you happen to use `sinon` and/or `sinon-chai` in your karma tests?  I found that when I commented out sinon-chai from my `frameworks` array, the error went away (unfortunately I need sinon-chai for my tests, though).  I also noticed [this issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/821) in the `sinon` project, that suggests a bug that was causing `setImmediate` polyfills to break.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was to switch from `karma-sinon-chai` to the alternative `karma-chai-sinon` module.

The difference between the two is that the latter has `chai`, `sinon` and `sinon-chai` as **peerDependencies** (allowing the user to choose what versions of these to use); where as the former has them as **dependencies** (and in particular it wants `sinon ~1.16.0`, which has a bug that leaks `setImmediate` into the global scope, breaking any `setImmediate` polyfills).

It wasn't clear from your question if you are using any of these frameworks; but if you are, this may be a fix for you too.

Comment: thank you so much, I believe that was it, I've spent around 5 hours on this, damn it